# How to not show path after cd command with CDPATH set?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, cd-command

Setting the CDPATH variable is very useful, but it results in some not very nice result: each time I use the `cd` command, the full path of directory I want to move is printed.

For example, if I am in my home directory and want to change directory to Desktop, result will be following:

```
~$ cd Desktop
/home/user/Desktop
~/Desktop$
```

This is kind of annoying, so my question is: how to avoid printing the path like this?

Comment: @rubynorails No, CDPATH is not the same as pushd. Here is a good article about CDPATH http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/04/what-is-cdpath.html

Comment: Thanks, that's a very useful link.  I have deleted my comment because I used some incorrect syntax in the [now irrelevant] `alias` code.

Comment: In case you want to suppress showing the path *only* when changing to a subdirectory, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456866/how-can-i-suppress-printing-the-full-path-to-subdirectories-when-using-cdpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the following alias should do it:

```
alias cd='>/dev/null cd'
```

This drops the output that `cd` would print on a successful, `CDPATH`-using directory change, while still printing error output when changing directories fails.