# How can I suppress printing the full path to subdirectories when using CDPATH=".:/some/path"?

Tags: bash, cd-command

I want to use bash's `CDPATH` to point to a directory of symlinks to directories that I access frequently.  However, doing:

```
CDPATH="~/symlinks"
```

causes `cd SUBDIR` to stop working if `./SUBDIR` and `~/symlinks/SUBDIR` both exist; `CDPATH` directories take precedence over the current working directory.

I tried to fix this by instead using:

```
CDPATH=".:~/symlinks"
```

and that does fix the precedence problem, but now `cd`ing to a subdirectory always prints its full path:

```
$ pwd
/foo/bar
$ cd baz
/foo/bar/baz
```

This is a bit annoying.  I know that I can [suppress all `cd` output by doing `alias cd='> /dev/null cd'`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245463/65110), but I do like the path being printed for other `CDPATH` entries (or when doing `cd -`).  Is there anything better that I can do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two clues:

- If `CDPATH` is non-existent or an empty string, then `cd SUBDIR` works fine and does not print extra spew.
- The bash manpage says:

> The variable `CDPATH`
> defines the search path for the directory containing  `dir`:  each
> directory  name  in  `CDPATH`  is  searched  for `dir`.  Alternative
> directory names in `CDPATH` are separated by a colon (`:`).  A  null
> directory  name  in `CDPATH` is the same as the current directory,
> i.e., ``.''.

The manpage seems to be oversimplifying: clearly a null directory name (i.e., an empty string) is *not* exactly the same as `.` since `CDPATH=.` generates extra output but `CDPATH=` does not.  However, since null directories are legal in `CDPATH`, and since a null directory doesn't generate extra output, we therefore can use:

```
# The first entry is intentionally an empty string.
CDPATH=":~/symlinks"
```

Testing (with bash 4.4.12) confirms that behaves as desired: `cd SUBDIR` changes to `./SUBDIR` instead of to `~/symlinks/SUBDIR` and does *not* print any extra spew.

Comment: Don't export CDPATH. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf48

Comment: @geirha Good point.  Fixed.